# Can we have a notification when a question was closed along a close vote?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm often putting close votes on questions, which I really think they should be deleted at all, and they won't be really salvaged by further (unless radical) editing.

So I'm often go back to these, to check if they were closed meanwhile, and have enough downvotes to delete them. This process may take some significant amount of time, depending on who's actually looked at the question.

It's likely I'll miss the point when they were actually closed, unless I'm reviewing my voting history (which is a bit tedious, and not very efficient).

So as the title says:
Can we have a notification, if a question was closed along my votes? May be by explicit opt in, only for those interested about it<sup>1)</sup>.
Alternatively to opt in, this feature could be implemented only for users with deletion privileges, and where the questions are eligible for deletion.

---

<sub>1) I am interested in face of the overwhelming amount of crap coming in at StackOverflow recently. Most of it needs deletion, not to confuse results given from Google (sry ABC-XYZ) searches</sub>

Comment: I wish there was some kind of viewable statistic when viewing a question that would tell you if or when it will be eligible for auto deletion via the roomba script. Many of the questions you're looking to delete will likely get auto deleted anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like this. No way I want to be notified each time a question is closed that I close voted on. *(yea i know you say "opt in" but SE doesn't have many opt in opt out notifications)* I don't have delete votes, but even if I did I doubt I'd like this notification. More filtering options on the user activity page would help with this issue as well as many other issues.

With that said, you can already find recently closed questions (and older ones) in which you close voted using SEDE.

Here is a @rene query I modified that should help you easily find these recently closed questions that you may want to delete vote now.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/352081/view-all-questions-that-were-closed-in-which-you-close-voted?UserId=1413395